# How can I install Leiningen packages behind a firewall?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript, lighttable

I use a local library to do some development, but the firewall prevents alot of internet sites. Is there a way to download artifacts manually?

My project.clj is:

```
https://github.com/zubairq/coils/blob/master/project.clj?
```

## Update

From the comments given I am understanding that the steps to take are:

```
1) Install Maven

2) Find out which jars are in my project (How can I do this based on my project.clj?)
```

Comment: You can download jar and install it using maven (see http://stackhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/adding-local-jars-in-maven-projectoverflow.com/questions/4955635/adding-local-jars-in-maven-project )

Comment: see also http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/

Comment: edbond, your link got broken http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/adding-local-jars-in-maven-project

Answer (score 8):

### Dependency Tree

In order to figure out which jars your project needs you can do:

```
$ lein deps :tree
```

Which will show you something that is called a "dependency tree". It will look similar to:

```
 [clj-time "0.5.0"]
   [joda-time "2.2"]
 [clojure-complete "0.2.3"]
 [org.myproject/some-proto "0.0.1-20130523.145830-9"]
   [org.flatland/protobuf "0.7.2"]
     [ordered-collections "0.4.0"]
     [org.flatland/schematic "0.1.0"]
     [org.flatland/useful "0.9.0"]
 [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.8.3862"]
   ...
```

### Installing Jars with Lein

One simple way to install manually downloaded jars would be to use "[lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo)":

```
$ lein localrepo install [-r repo-path] 
                         [-p pom-file] 
                         <filename> 
                         <[groupId/]artifactId> 
                         <version>
```

Here are a couple of examples (given that you have downloaded the jars):

```
$ lein localrepo install foo-1.0.6.jar com.example/foo 1.0.6

$ lein localrepo install foomatic-1.3.9.jar foomatic 1.3.9
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo/blob/master/README.md) for more features and examples.

### Installing lein-localrepo

You can install `lein-localrepo` as a plugin by adding the following to your `~/.lein/profiles.clj`:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.2"]]}}
```

---

### Lein Behind a Proxy Server

In case it is "ok" to use a proxy server, you can add it to `~/.lein/profiles.clj` under `jvm-opts`

```
{:user {:jvm-opts ["-Dhttp.proxyHost=168.1.1.104" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"]}}
```

where `user` is a profile name to use.

Or you can export `http_proxy` environment variable [before launching lein](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/HTTP-Proxies).

Comment: Great answer. I am still trying to get the local lein repository working

Comment: It still is not working as now I have another problem, Lein will not self install behind the firewall. I will award you the prize anyway, as I think I will be trying for quite a while to get this working

Comment: The error I get when trying to self-install leiningen is: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

Comment: When I do  lein localrepo install I get an error: "Could not transfer artifact lein-newnew:lein-newnew:pom:0.3.5 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused"

Comment: `http_proxy` doesn't work for me, but `https_proxy` does.